# Generating/Simulating numbers truncated GPD

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, truncate, quantile

I'm trying to generate a random sample from the truncated GPD (Generalized Pareto Distribution). In order to do just that, I've begun with writing the CDF and quantile functions of the GPD:

```
##CDF of the GPD
pGPD <- function(q, xi = 1, mu = 0, beta = 1, lower.tail = TRUE){ 
  shape = xi
  location = mu
  scale = beta

  # Probability:
  p = .pepd(q, location, scale, shape, lower.tail)

  # Return Value:
  p
}

##Quantile function (inverse of CDF) of GPD
qGPD <- function(p, xi = 1, mu = 0, beta = 1, lower.tail = TRUE){   
  shape = xi
  location = mu
  scale = beta

  # Quantiles:
  q = .qepd(p, location, scale, shape, lower.tail)

  # Return Value:
  q
}

##Generate random numbers of GPD-distribution
rGPD <- function(n, xi = 1, mu = 0, beta = 1){   
  shape = xi
  location = mu
  scale = beta

  # Random Variates:
  r = .repd(n, location, scale, shape)

  # Return Value:
  r
}

.pepd <- function(q, location = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0, lower.tail = TRUE) {
    # Check:
    stopifnot(min(scale) > 0) 
    stopifnot(length(shape) == 1) 

    # Probability:
    q <- pmax(q - location, 0)/scale
    if (shape == 0) 
      p <- 1 - exp(-q)
    else {
      p <- pmax(1 + shape * q, 0)
      p <- 1 - p^(-1/shape)
    }

    # Lower Tail:
    if (!lower.tail) 
      p <- 1 - p

    # Return Value: 
    p
  }

.qepd <-function(p, location = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0, lower.tail = TRUE){ 
    # Check:
    stopifnot(min(scale) > 0) 
    stopifnot(length(shape) == 1)
    stopifnot(min(p, na.rm = TRUE) >= 0)
    stopifnot(max(p, na.rm = TRUE) <= 1) 

    # Lower Tail:
    if (lower.tail) 
      p <- 1 - p

    # Quantiles:
    if (shape == 0) {
      q = location - scale * log(p)
    } else {
      q = location + scale * (p^(-shape) - 1)/shape
    }

    # Return Value: 
    q
  }

.repd <- 
  function(n, location = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0) {
    # Check:
    stopifnot(min(scale) > 0) 
    stopifnot(length(shape) == 1)

    # Random Variates:
    if (shape == 0) {
      r = location + scale * rexp(n)
    } else {
      r = location + scale * (runif(n)^(-shape) - 1)/shape
    }

    # Return Value:
    r
  }
```

This all works perfectly. Now, I want to generate numbers from the Truncated GPD and to do that, I've used the following relation:

[image]

where Q resembles the quantile functions of the subscript and F_{GPD}(T) is the CDF of the GPD. Using this, I've written the following code:

```
##Quantiles truncated GPD
qtGPD <- function (p,q,xi=1,mu=0,beta=1,lower.tail=TRUE){
  ans= qGPD(p*pGPD(q,xi,mu,beta,lower.tail), 
            xi,mu,beta, lower.tail)
  print(paste0("Generated from the ", 100*p, "th% quantile"))
  return (ans)
}

rtGPD <- function (n,q,xi=1,mu=0,beta=1,lower.tail=TRUE){
  qtGPD(p= runif(n),q,xi,mu,beta,lower.tail)
}
```

But now, if I want for example to generate numbers from the 99th% quantile truncated GPD with the function rtGPD it doesn't work, because my p value keeps changing. So, what am I doing wrong or how can I fix this? All I want is to generate numbers from the truncated GPD at the 99th% quantile for example, or at the 97.5% quantile or... you get the idea.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** For example, if you run the following code:

```
set.seed(10)
A= rGPD(10)
sort(A)

qtGPD(0.99,2)
rtGPD(10,2)
```

Then you should normally get a vector A, with random values from the GPD which can be bigger than 1, like expected.

With the command `qtGPD(O.99,2)`, one obtains

```
[1] "Generated from the 99th% quantile"
[1] 1.941176
```

which is also OK. But if you then run `rtGPD(10,2)`, a function that I want to give me random values for the truncated GPD, you get different values for p in runif(10), all generated from different quantiles. I just want to generate/simulate random numbers for the truncated GPD at a certain quantile, for example the 99% quantile. But this code isn't letting me do that.

Comment: Could you add a line of code indicating what you want & also display the results and explain why the results are not what you are looking for? Good to `set.seed` so that we can reproduce.

Comment: @EricWang, updated. You can also simulate a plot of the values of rtGPD(i), for i in 1, ..., 100, and see that it will not follow the truncated GPD.

Comment: What is your 99% quantile? Is it the truncation cutoff point of your GDP? Based on my understanding, `qtGPD(0.99,2)` returns the 99% quantile of a truncated GDP which is truncated at (-inf, 2).

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but yes, I want it to be the truncation cutoff point.